# Меню через inline keyboard, telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Всех приветствую, задался вопросом нужно создать меню через библиотеку pyTelegramBotApi, само меню уже есть и функционирует, вопрос в том как сделать чтобы сообщение которые выводилось видел только тот что вызвал это меню, бот добавлен в группу, через message.from_user.id не подходит, потому что пишется в самом боте, а надо в группе.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы сообщение видел только определенный юзер находящийся в группе? Никак

Comment: Жаль, а в aiogram есть такая функция?

Comment: Это не возможно в целом. Даже через апи вы этого не сделаете.